# Connecting PC speaker to Arduino

Tags: pwm, audio

I've looted this speaker from my old PC and trying to understand how to connect it to Arduino to produce simple sound notification (and not fry anything in the process).

As far as I understand this is a piezo speaker, there is no markings on it. Here is how it looks:

[image: speaker front]
[image: speaker back]

How do I connect\control it?

Should I connect it to PWM pin? If so, what are the safe values to output on PWM pin?

Should I use resistor when connecting speaker? What resistor should I use?

Comment: Take a look at the [tone()](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/tone) function, it may suit your purpose.

Comment: As far as connections go, I would connect the red wire to a PWM pin and the black one to a GND pin, but I'm not sure if a resistor is needed, wait for someone more expert than me to answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

No need for a resistor. Just connect black to ground, and red to a IO pin. Use the [tone](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/tone) function to specify a frequency.

Comment: I'd recommend using a resistor. The piezo conducts quite well and might fry the pin. http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Tone Also see http://www.uchobby.com/index.php/2007/11/11/arduino-sound-part-1/

Comment: @MrJones A resistor might be needed for (electromagnetic) speakers, not for piezos. A piezo is more like a capacitor, and doesn't conduct any current.

Comment: Why is no resistor needed? I don't exactly know OP's speaker, but my speaker says 8 Ohm. 8 Ohm at 5V is much more than an Arduino can handle, isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasWeller OPs "Speaker" is actually a piezo. A piezo you can drive with an Arduino pin. With a (8-ohm) speaker, you can't do that.